# add some js to contentscript using pagemod

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

i'm trying to create new firefox extension based on page-mod 
i used that code which execute a js file

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
  var data = require('sdk/self').data;

  pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.com",
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.11.0.min.js'),

 data.url('detecter.js')]        
});
```

Then i'm trying to add a code for example a google adsense code inside detector.js file 
any help apreciated !

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- addon -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="*****"
     data-ad-slot="****"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: i use $('body').append('<script></script>')
and it don't work 
i need any method to append the google adsense code to browsed page using page mod

Comment: have you tried this?  $("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + script + '"></script>');

Comment: So i am going to write in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + script + '"></script>');
```